# welcome file list page not loading by default

Tags: jsp, websphere-liberty, welcome-file

I have deployed an application on **Websphere Liberty**.

When I visit my homepage: `localhost:8080/myapp` it shows a blank page.

However when I go to `localhost:8080/myapp/jsp/status.jsp` it displays the page I need.

In my `web.xml` I have set the welcome file list as:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.netflix.eureka.EurekaBootStrap</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>statusFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.netflix.eureka.StatusFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>requestAuthFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.netflix.eureka.ServerRequestAuthFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>rateLimitingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.netflix.eureka.RateLimitingFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>gzipEncodingEnforcingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.netflix.eureka.GzipEncodingEnforcingFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>jersey</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.WebPageContentRegex</param-name>
      <param-value>/(flex|images|js|css|jsp)/.*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.sun.jersey;com.netflix</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <!-- GZIP content encoding/decoding -->
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
      <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
      <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>statusFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>requestAuthFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <!-- Uncomment this to enable rate limiter filter.
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>rateLimitingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/v2/apps</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/v2/apps/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  -->

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>gzipEncodingEnforcingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/v2/apps</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/v2/apps/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>jersey</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>jsp/status.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

The file directory structure is:

```
META-INF
WEB-INF
  --web.xml
jsp
  --status.jsp
```

I am not able to figure out what is wrong in my setting.

Comment: you need to show full web.xml.

Comment: @SabirKhan updated

Comment: You specify three filters for your default URL, are all those filters getting kicked? Is this an issue only on **Websphere Liberty** and not on any other container?

Comment: @SabirKhan yes only on liberty. On tomcat this works fine

Comment: Generally, Liberty uses CXF and not Jersey (and it's an internal detail). So, if you're opting into Jersey... what Liberty features are enabled? Some of ours can be turned off so they don't fight with Jersey.

Answer (score 1):

Which Jeresy version you're using? Better you use jersey version 2.0

There is a known issue on jersey 1.8 
checkout [here](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-880)

can you add below under `ServletContainer` Filter and give a try?

```
<init-param>
<param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.JSPTemplatesBasePath</param-name>
 <param-value>/WEB-INF/jsp/*.jsp</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: still no difference

Comment: Next time, as long as you can't reproduce the so far described problem on your own and thus can't explain nor solve it by experience, then please post "Try this" shoot-in-the-darks as comments first, not as answers. The chance is big that they're just wrong and then you would be misguiding and confusing to future readers stumbling on a simliar problem.